# .html() not show result in jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

this is code:

```
$(function () {

  $("#test").gmap3({
    marker: {
      latLng: [46.578498, 2.457275],
      options: {
        draggable: true
      },
      events: {
        dragend: function (marker) {
          var position = (marker.getPosition());
          //alert (position)
          //alert($("#position").html(position));
          //alert($("#map").append('position: ',position));
          $("#map").append(marker.getPosition());
        }

      }
    },
    map: {
      options: {
        zoom: 5
      }
    }
  });
});
```

this is gmap3 for google map work true , 
problem is here :

```
 dragend: function (marker) {
     var position = (marker.getPosition());
     $("#map").html(position);
 }
```

html:

```
<div id="map" > </div>
<div id="position" > </div>
```

when use alert show position number corectly but just dont show in  div

Comment: My guess would be `#map` either doesn't exist or isn't visible.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the .text('test123') function to set the div text? What is you do a alert of div.length (alert('$('#map').length)). What is the returned value?

Comment: Can you show your html code ?

Comment: @Kevin B : <div id="test" class="gmap3"></div>
    <div id="map" ></div>
    <div id="position" ></div> both of div is exist.

Comment: @Philippe :  <body>

    <div id="test" class="gmap3"></div>
    <div id="map" > </div>
    <div id="position" ></div>
  </body>

Comment: @shahriyarshahriyar That belongs in your question, click the `"edit"` button below the tags.

Comment: @shahriyar3 what of css lines are set for the #map div? The text isn't the same as the background color?

Comment: @benz no any css code. just this 2 div and include id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an `typeof Object`, Try using `$("#map").html(position.toString());` instead so you should get an output.

Also, you can just do `var position = marker.getPosition();` without extra brackets. Cheers.